# Problems with new member registration email and SolSpace User

Tags: solspace, solspace-user

We are using SolSpace User to handle key invites and member signup and also using the screen name override feature.

There are quite a few members on this site, so we added the member_id field to the screen name override, so it's like this: first_name|last_name|member_id.

That works great for dealing with conflicting screen names, but the EE email that goes out to the admin to let him know that a new member registered is now showing "garbage" for the name.

```
Member name: 4f99fa19c1d3b11c9ad517b0c073e450
```

Thoughts?

Comment: I updated all modules and upgraded EE to 2.8.1 and using User 3.5.3. 

Now the {email} address field in the notification email is blank.

I removed the |member_id from the screen name override and the notification email is showing the name correctly again (first_name|last_name).

Comment: Is this for the email that is sent to the admin when a user fills a registration form and EE's "Require Member Account Activation?" setting is set to **Manual activation by an administrator**? Is the email the content of the **Admin Notification of New Member Registration** message page template (set in CP => Design => Message Pages => Email Notifications)?

Comment: This is indeed the email sent to the admin.

Require manual activation is off. It is currently set to "No activation required".

And yes, the email notification is the "admin notification" template.



`New member registration site: {site_name}

Member name: {name}
Email: {email}`

Comment: @Solspace - Just checking back in for any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm that the screen_name override is a temporary hash at the point where the admin email notification is being sent. This is caused by member_id in the User code. I'll report this, but unfortunately we don't have an ETA for possible fixing/implementation. The workaround for now would be to not use member_id in the screen_name override, or use something other than the screen_name in the admin notification.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to add a unique identifier to the screen name override then?

Comment: Perhaps an additional custom member field named "unique identifier" could be used? You could make it a hidden field in the registration form and populate a random string or hash to make unique identifiers.